# asp:table, make all rows under main rows, (indcated by tr.CssClass = "rowEntry";) hidden at page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Long time listener, first time caller..

I'm terrible with jquery, so bear with me, this should be a quick answer for those in the know.

I have a programmatically created asp:table and have set the top level rows to:  tr.CssClass = "rowEntry".

I have an ajax toggle like the below which successfully toggles the secondary rows I want hidden:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".rowEntry").click(function () {
            $(this).next().toggle(300);
            $(this).next().next().toggle(300);

        });
    });

</script>
```

Now, the question.. how do I set these rows to be hidden from page load? If I set the css on the detail rows .ie. .rowDetails td { display:none; } - then they are hidden and I can't get them to toggle on or off.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

`toggle` should work fine with elements even if they're initially set to `display:none;`. However, it appears your CSS is hiding the `<td>` elements, but `toggle()` is being invoked on one or more `<tr>` elements. You need to apply the CSS to the same element that is being toggled--in this case, the row(s), not the cells. E.g.,

`.rowDetails { display: none; }`

rather than

`.rowDetails td { display: none; }`

Comment: Brilliant!.. yes.. CSS is a weak point of mine.

Many thanks!

Comment: Don't know if supplementary questions are welcomed or frowned upon but I'm going to try anyhow :)

I have a down arrow, indicating the row toggle ability (for the 2 rows beneath it), and I'd like to swap it for an up arrow once the row is expanded, indicating that it can be collapsed.

I currently have the arrow as an image declaration inside a programatically generated cell, i.e:
td0.Text = "<img src=\"Images/expandTriangle1.gif\" height=\"12px\" />";

What would be the favored way of toggling this image?

Thanks..

Comment: Certainly! There are multiple ways you can do this, but since you're already using `toggle`...you can include your 2nd image (_assuming_ it is named `collapseTriangle1.gif`) in your `td0.Text` value, like so: `td0.Text = "<img src=\"Images/expandTriangle1.gif\" height=\"12px\" /><img src=\"Images/collapseTriangle1.gif\" height=\"12px\" style=\"display:none;\" />"` As you can see, it's hidden by default. Then, in your JavaScript after `$(this).next().next().toggle(300);` try: `$('td:first img', $(this)).toggle();`. This jQuery says: toggle all `<img>` in the first `<td>` of the clicked row.

Comment: Certainly! If I have answered your question please feel free to mark my answer as accepted.